# System.Data.Spatial or System.Data.Entity.Spatial

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geospatial

I was trying to add an `DbGeography` type to a test project because I wanted to use the `Intersects` method to see if some latitude longitude coordinates were within an area stored on a table in a  geography type column on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am confused about the differences between:

[System.Data.Entity.Spatial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.spatial.aspx)

and

[System.Data.Spatial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.aspx)

Is it true that if I want to use the geography data stored on my database that I have to reference Entity Framework in my project?

Does adding Entity Framework to an app add any overhead in terms of memory used in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two classes you mentioned are used by different versions of Entity Framework.

You can use [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) class, [STIntersects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stintersects%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) method instead. This class does not require Enity Framework to be referenced.